# Config and test rosemacs

Tags: ros, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

So, through some miracle I installed roslisp and rosemacs... I think (it´s kinetic).  What I´d really like to do is test it.  I´ve never used emacs and lisp before but I hear it´s the best development environment ever.  Where do I start?  How do I know if emacs is configured to connect to (or start ) a lisp session?

Any advice is appreciated.

=====  Update after last reply ===========
Actually, I was thinking more along the lines of getting emacs to talk to SBCL with the ROS configuration through slime.  Not the internal emacs lisp.  I did have some success with this.  I edited the .emacs file in home directory to include this:

(add-to-list 'load-path "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/emacs/site-lisp")
;; or whatever your install space is + "/share/emacs/site-lisp"
(require 'rosemacs-config).

## It added some interesting ros-related buffers to emacs.  I´m till trying to figure out slime and connecting to sbcl

======== Update after Gaya´s suggestion to just do rosrun roslisp_repl roslisp_repl ========

Yes.  I tried this earlier but couldn´t get roslisp_repl to install.  HOWEVER, it finally ALMOST installed.  I discovered that nothing (like knowrob) is properly installing (catkin making) on my system because rosjava didn´t come with the kinetic installation.  Nor is there any way to install it, that I can see.  There is not even a kinetic rosjava installation available from source:

wstool init -j4 ~/rosjava/src https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rosjava/rosjava/kinetic/rosjava.rosinstall
Using initial elements from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rosjava/rosjava/kinetic/rosjava.rosinstall
ERROR in config: Unable to download URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rosjava/rosjava/kinetic/rosjava.rosinstall]: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

So, it looks like I may be screwed here.  If everything requires rosjava and there is no rosjava available for kinetic... well... punt.

Sincerely,

-Todd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241296/config-and-test-rosemacs/) by [toddcpierce](https://answers.ros.org/users/25497/toddcpierce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2016-08-09**:
You followed the setup instructions for non-lisp developers of rosemacs. What you should try instead is the instructions for lisp developers. You can simply try to `rosrun roslisp_repl roslisp_repl` and that will start the lisp shell in an Emacs. There are also roslisp tutorials around, try those. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Emacs ships with lisp and you can always evaluate lisp in the scratch buffer.  Emacs also ships with "An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp" which you can find using the info command.

---

Originally posted by [mcshicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/27255/mcshicks/) with karma: 51 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1